# change sub folder name with main domain or replace home directory using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have directory structure like this,

```
/public_html
  index.php      
  /test
    index.php
```

And 1 domain `test.com` and 1 sub-domain `abc.test.com` 
Now when user visit `test.com` home directory for that is `public_html`
And if user visit `abc.test.com` home directory is `public_html/test`

I want if user visit `test.com` it point to `test.com/test`
OR if user visit `abc.test.com` it shows `test.com` (not redirecting, only rewrite)
OR if user visit `test.com` need to change home directory from `public_html` to `public_html/test`.

Basically what i want to do is, i have 2 site one is live and one is test. now i want user to use my test site if they visit live(because if there is any bug i can change it back to live quickly instead of move whole files and folder to live).

Is there any way to do like this using `htaccess`?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you simply defined two separate http hosts with separate document roots?

Comment: @arkascha you mean from cpanel?

Comment: However you configure your http server. If you use `cpanel` for that, then yes, but I have no experience with that tool myself, so I cannot help there.

Comment: @arkascha i have no access to change home directory from cpanel. so thats why i want to do using `htaccess`. is there any way to do like this using `htaccess`?